# google search results using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am setting up a test to perform a search and after the search is complete, i want to capture the results line that says "About xxx results (x.xx seconds)"
Here's the code snippet

```
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();


    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElementById("lst-ib");
    searchBox.sendKeys("search text");

    WebElement clickSearch = driver.findElementByXPath("html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/button");
    clickSearch.click();



    WebElement results = driver.findElementByXPath("html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div");
    System.out.println(results);
```

Comment: so are you getting any error or not getting the proper output? whats the issue , Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getText()` method to get the text form a element. In your case you need to do something like below,

```
WebElement results = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div"));
System.out.println(results.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you need to capture would have the selector:

Css:

```
#resultStats
```

Xpath:

```
//div[@id='resultStats']
```

If you need to return the text:

```
//div[@id='resultStats']//text()
```

Or use find and getText() method.